# Read data from excel file

Tags: java, excel, xls

I have searched through StackOverflow, but didn't find a clear answer to my question.

I have a simple 2 columns and 24 rows xlsx (excel) file (later on this file will have more columns and rows , and also eventually it will have different sheets).

First row is header row: year=x and population=y, and for each header I want to read the rows below. Later on I want to be able to use this information to create a dynamic plot (x,y),

So I think I need to save the x and y information in variables. Below is my pseudo code.

```
//Sheet Pop

final String POP = "Pop";   
int startRowHeader = 1,      
    startRowNumeric = 2,     
    startColNumeric = 1, 
    nrOfCols = 0,
    nrOfRows  = 0;

int nrOfSheets = excelFile.getWorkbook().getNumberOfSheets(); 
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet1 = excelFile.getWorkbook().getSheetAt(0);  
String[] sheets = {POP};
boolean sheetExists;
String activeSheet = "";   

nrOfCols = sheet1.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
 nrOfRows = excelFile.getLastRowNum(POP);

try {

    for (String sheet : sheets) {
        sheetExists = false;
        for (int sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < nrOfSheets; sheetIndex++) {
        if (sheet.equalsIgnoreCase( excelFile.getWorkbook().getSheetName(sheetIndex))) { 
                SheetExists = true; 
            }
        }
        if (!sheetExists) {
            throw new Exception("Sheet " + sheet + " is missing!");
        }
    } 


    //Take off!

    // Sheet Pop
    activeSheet = sheets[0];

    for(int j=0; j < nrOfCols; j++) {
        for(int i=0; i<nrofRows; i++) {
            column[i] = (int)excelFile.getCellNumericValue(POP, startRowNumeric, startColNumeric);  
        }
    } 

}  catch (Exception e) {
    traceln(" ..... ");
    traceln("Error in sheet: " + activeSheet);
    traceln("Message: " + e.getMessage());  //Write out in console
}
```

Comment: what exactly is your problem? are you getting an exception?

Comment: @gaurav5430. I'm not sure where I should save the data from the excel file to use it as variables when I want to plot the dynamical graph. Also, how do I get the cell values for each column? That is all the years for header year and the population for each year in header Population?

Comment: how about using a 2d array or a array of Point class ( a custom class with int x annd int y as members) ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I'm rather new at Java. How would I accomplish that? Couldn't I use something like "getcellnumeric value"?

Answer (score 1):

create a new class:

```
public class Point {
        int x;
        int y;

}
```

in your main function create a

```
List<Point> allPoints = new List<Point>();
```

then add the points you read from excel to this List

do this in a loop

```
Point p = new Point();
p.x = xCoordinateFromExcel;
p.y = yCoordinateFromExcel;

allPoints.add(p);
```

also consider adding constructor and getter/setters to your Point class.

also you might want to use the Point class available in java.awt directly.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html

EDIT: regarding fetching values from excel
this is what i understand from your question
you have 24 rows with 2 columns
first column has x, second column has y value

so you can just do something like this in a loop

```
for(int i=0;i<24;i++){
    Row row = sheet.getRow(i);    
    Cell cellX = row.getCell(1);
    Cell cellY = row.getCell(2);

//assign to point class
...
}
```

dont forget to parse it to int, or use getNumericCellValue()
http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getNumericCellValue()

Comment: `java.util.List` is an interface, you cannot instantiate it... line should read `List<Point> allPoints = new ArrayList<Point>();`

Comment: @Samy How would I read in the data in to this arraylist? That is, how do I get each cell value (below header) for each column?

Comment: Well your question is twofold: parse Excel file and store the values in your program. This answers the storing part. Regarding Excel parsing you can try `Apache POI HSSF` (which stands for Horrible Spread Sheet Format! I love it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `java.util.ArrayList` of `java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double`

Declare the list:

```
ArrayList<Point2D.Double> points = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then for each row:

```
// Read x
// Read y
Point2D.Double p = new Point2D.Double(x, y);
/// And add to the list: 
points.add(p);
```

Comment: Point2D.double gives me an arraylist of doubles. Can I possibly change the numbers in the list to integers?

Comment: Either cast the values to integers, or write a custom integer class (preferably sub-classing `java.awt.Point` to inherit all the functionality)